# How to get the size of the browser inner space if it were maximized in pixels through javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to know the client available screen size, I mean the size of the browser inner space if it were maximized in pixels. I need some code that works on both IE and Firefox at least.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screen.availWidth/Height`  should work in most browsers.

```
alert(window.screen.availWidth);
```

- [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.availWidth)
- [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer... I'll give it a try on Monday and let you know but as far as I understood from that references it gives you the available size to the window not the browser's inner space (I mean  the window.available height minus the menu/url/tabs bar on the browser... ) am I right?

Comment: @Johann yes, these will give the maximum size available to a *window*. As far as I know, there is no way to find out the maximum theoretical *document* size